# Why the SublimeCodeIntel plugin doesn't show autocompletion for the Flask module?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I have a problem with the proper working of the Sublime​Code​Intel plugin (later named "SCI" in brief). When I try to import Flask class from the flask module I expected that the SCI give me autocompletion for that class. Unfortunately, SCI did not recognize the Flask class and any methods in this case. **What's wrong with SublimeCodeIntel? Why it doesn't recognize classes, methods, etc. for the Flask module?**

See following screenshots and output from the `codeintel.log` log file.

Screenshots:

[image: SublimeCodeIntel and Flask - screen1]
[image: SublimeCodeIntel and Flask - screen2]

Output from the ```codeintel.log`` log file:

```
Starting logging SublimeCodeIntel v2.0.6 ...
============================================
+ Info: processing `Python': please wait...
New env with catalogs for 'Python': PyWin32
...
Updating indexes for 'Python'... The first time this can take a while.
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\hello-flask.py' lang: Python
Doing CodeIntel for 'Python' (hold on)...
eval 'Flask' at hello-flask.py#2  <Trigger 'python-defn-defn' at 21 (explicit)>
start scope is (<Element 'scope' at 0x0560B8B0>, [])
find 'Flask ...' starting at (<Element 'scope' at 0x0560B8B0>, []):
is blob 'flask' from <Python curdirlib>? no
is blob 'flask' from <Python envlib>? no
is blob 'flask' from <Python sitelib>? yes
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\exthook.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\debughelpers.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\module.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\signals.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\globals.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\views.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\_compat.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\wrappers.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\logging.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\sessions.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\helpers.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\templating.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\ext\\__init__.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\testsuite\\__init__.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\ctx.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\json.py' lang: Python
+ Info: Doing CodeIntel for 'Python' (hold on)...
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\config.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\testing.py' lang: Python
scan_purelang: path: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\blueprints.py' lang: Python
imports:: setting reldirlib to: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask'
is blob 'app' from <Python curdirlib>? no
is blob 'app.Flask' from <Python curdirlib>? no
could not import 'Flask' from <Element 'import' at 0x0560B9F0>
is blob 'flask.Flask' from <Python curdirlib>? no
is blob 'flask.Flask' from <Python envlib>? no
is blob 'flask.Flask' from <Python sitelib>? no
is blob 'flask.Flask' from <Python cataloglib: PyWin32>? no
is blob 'flask.Flask' from <python-2.7 stdlib>? no
could not import 'Flask' from <Element 'import' at 0x0560B6F0>
is 'Flask' accessible on (<Element 'scope' at 0x0560B8B0>, [])? no
is 'Flask' accessible on (<Element 'scope' at 0x05606A70>, [])? no
evaluating 'Flask' at test-2.py#2: could not resolve first part of 'Flask'
done eval: eval error
...
eval 'app.route' at hello-flask.py#6  <Trigger 'python-calltip-call-signature' at 60 (explicit)>
start scope is (<Element 'scope' at 0x05606070>, [])
find 'app ...' starting at (<Element 'scope' at 0x05606070>, []):
is 'app' accessible on (<Element 'scope' at 0x05606070>, [])? yes: <Element 'variable' at 0x056062F0>
resolve getattr 'route' on <Element 'variable' at 0x056062F0> in (<Element 'scope' at 0x05606070>, []):
resolve 'Flask()' type inference for <Element 'variable' at 0x056062F0>:
find 'Flask ...' starting at (<Element 'scope' at 0x05606070>, []):
is blob 'flask' from <Python curdirlib>? no
is blob 'flask' from <Python envlib>? no
is blob 'flask' from <Python sitelib>? yes
imports:: setting reldirlib to: 'C:\\Python\\tmp\\flasky\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\flask'
is blob 'app' from <Python curdirlib>? no
is blob 'app.Flask' from <Python curdirlib>? no
could not import 'Flask' from <Element 'import' at 0x02CD0870>
is blob 'flask.Flask' from <Python curdirlib>? no
is blob 'flask.Flask' from <Python envlib>? no
is blob 'flask.Flask' from <Python sitelib>? no
is blob 'flask.Flask' from <Python cataloglib: PyWin32>? no
is blob 'flask.Flask' from <python-2.7 stdlib>? no
could not import 'Flask' from <Element 'import' at 0x05606BF0>
is 'Flask' accessible on (<Element 'scope' at 0x05606070>, [])? no
is 'Flask' accessible on (<Element 'scope' at 0x05606A70>, [])? no
evaluating 'app.route' at hello-flask.py#6: could not resolve first part of 'Flask()'
done eval: eval error
```

---

BTW, I was angry at the SublimeCodeIntel plugin and tried the [SublimeJEDI](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Jedi%20-%20Python%20autocompletion) plugin. IMHO, SublimeJEDI is much better for the Python coding. See the following screenshots with no problem in the SublimeJEDI with autocompletion.

[image: SublimeJEDI screen 1]
[image: SublimeJEDI screen 2]

From my experience in using both plugins I have the following opinion.

**Pros of the SublimeJEDI plugin in comparison to the SublimeCodeIntel plugin:**

- Extremely fast
- Lightweight
- Easy to configure and well documented
- No problematic

**Pros of the SublimeCodeIntel plugin:**

- Support many languages (not only Python)

Comment: Sorry, what is the question?

Comment: @jonrsharpe See below the output. There are two questions. ;-)

Comment: are you having issues with any other modules in your virtualenv? It likely is simply a matter of settings with SCI.

Comment: @MattDMo No, the SublimeCodeIntel has a problem only with the Flask module. I think my SCI settings are correct.